# Ordinal arithmetic

Tags: logic, arithmetic

How can I compute with ordinals in mathematica? For instance, I'd like to query $2+\omega > 1 + 2 \omega$.

Comment: What have you tried? I've not encountered ordinal arithmetic before so it would be helpful to know the rules - the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) is a bit hard to follow.

Comment: @flinty, I was expecting there would be a a package for this in mathematica

Comment: Maple includes the [Ordinals](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Ordinals) package to this end.